# Starting amazon ec2 server with Putty

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, putty

I use Putty to run the ec2 server with this code,

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but when I shut Putty down, the server is also shut down too.

In order to keep the ec2 server activated, even I shut Putty down how do I start server??

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is "manage.py"? What API calls is it making? Shutting down a client shouldn't shut down an EC2 instance.

Comment: You follow the directions in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/) for running your Python framework app as a service using something like uwsgi or gunicorn.

Comment: You're apparently talking about Django, nothing to do with EC2. Besides a *production* website shouldn't be running through `manage.py` - use Apache or uwsgi or similar.

Comment: This is not an EC2 question.